# How can I center text in a HTML table cell which has a fake rowspan? (two or more tds without border at the cell boundaries)

Tags: html, css, dompdf

I'm using DOMPDF to convert HTML to PDF but whenever a page break occurs and  rowspan is used then the table is broken. I fixed it by removing the rowspan and removing the border (border-bottom: none). Furthermore tds are inserted.

It looks like this:

```html
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Test 1</th>
            <th>Test 2</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="border-bottom:none">Hello, world!</td>
            <td>Test 3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="border-bottom:none;border-top:none;"></td>
            <td>Test 3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="border-top:none"></td>
            <td>Test 3</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Now I want to vertically align "Hello, world!" to the center relative to the 3 tds.
How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

```html
<div>
  <div style="display:flex;">
    <div style="width:200px;">
      Test 1
    </div>
    <div style="width:200px;">
      Test 2
    </div>
  </div>
  <div style="display:table;">
    <div style="width: 200px;display: table-cell;vertical-align: middle;">
      Hello World
    </div>
    <div style="width:200px;">
      <div>
        Test 3
      </div>
      <div>
        Test 3
      </div>
 <div>
        Test 3
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you want to achieved in DOMPDF then div will help (you have to used inline css )

Comment: This is a good solution. Now I have to automatize this so that the user can create the table in ckeditor and an algorithm converts it to div

Answer (score 0):

use for align it to the middle

```html
<td align="center"></td>
```

Comment: That doesn't work. Because it centers the text only for the first td. It should be centered relative to all 3 tds